# ProgressBar backround showing on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, progress-bar

Im using ProgressBars in a ListView.
The Background is white and the ProgressBar default.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/timerProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />
```

When I open the app in my 4.2.2 emulator everything looks normal (blue bar with gray background)

But on my 4.2.2 (Gnex) phone its just the blue bar and no background at all (the white background from the parent view).

Any idea what the problem could be?

EDIT: Used a custom ProgressBar before (reverse) but its the same with the android default.

Comment: Try to uninstall app from device, and build again.

Comment: tried this already, delete everything and uninstalled.